# unable to fetch value from JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm unable to fetch JSON value to check if the person is wearing glasses while taking photo, the value relies in four arrays: photos, tags, attributes and glasses, I want to check the value "value" is true or false. I use alert() to test if value fetched but nothing comes out. I don't know which part gets wrong

I use JavaScript to fetch the JSON value as follows:

```
var facesDet = $.getJSON( APIdetect, function() {
  console.log( "success" );
  console.log(facesDet);
})

.done(function (facesDet, tid) {
    var VALUEIWANT = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes[0].gender[0].value;

});
```

The JSON value looks as follows:

```
{
"photos" : [
    {
        "url" : "http://tinyurl.com/673cksr",
        "pid" : "F@0c95576847e9cd7123f1e304476b59ae_59ec9bb2ad15f",
        "width" : 375,
        "height" : 409,
        "tags" : [
            {
                "tid" : "TEMP_F@0c95576847e9cd7123f1e304b1dcbe53_59ec9bb2ad15f_56.53_40.83_0_1",
                "recognizable" : true,
                "confirmed" : false,
                "manual" : false,
                "width" : 30.67,
                "height" : 28.12,
                "center" : { "x" : 56.53, "y" : 40.83},
                "eye_left" : { "x" : 66.93, "y" : 33.99},
                "eye_right" : { "x" : 51.73, "y" : 33.99},
                "yaw" : -16,
                "roll" : 0,
                "pitch" : 0,
                "attributes" : {
                    "face" : { "value" : "true", "confidence" : 82 },
                    "gender" : { "value" : "female", "confidence" : 80 },
                    "glasses":{"value" : "true", "confidence" : 100},
                    "dark_glasses":{"value" : "true", "confidence" : 72},
                    "smiling":{"value" : "false", "confidence" : 35}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status" : "success",
"usage" : {
    "used" : 1,
    "remaining" : 99,
    "limit" : 100,
    "reset_time_text" : "Fri, 21 September 2012 12:57:19 +0000",
    "reset_time" : 1348232239
}
}
```

Comment: use this 'facesDet=JSON.parse(facesDet)' and then use this                   ' **var VALUEIWANT=facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.gender.value;** '

Comment: attributes and gender are `Objects` not `Arrays` so you would get the properties like so. `facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.gender.value` or using the array bracket syntax `facesDet.photos[0].tags[0]['attributes']['gender']['value']`

Comment: Thank you for spotting my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tryed to take value from gender like from array:

```
var VALUEIWANT = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes[0].gender[0].value;
```

But in your json its object, so you should use:

```
var VALUEIWANT = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.gender.value;
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting my problem, since I saw curly bracket, so I thought it's an array, I should realise only values encompassed with [] is array.

Answer (score 2):

Your access is wrong. You have an object, but you treat it like an array

```
var VALUEIWANT = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes[0].gender[0].value;
//                                                    ^^^  and  ^^^
```

right access:

```
var VALUEIWANT = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.gender.value;
```

data:

```
"attributes" : {
    "face" : { "value" : "true", "confidence" : 82 },
    "gender" : { "value" : "female", "confidence" : 80 },
    "glasses":{"value" : "true", "confidence" : 100},
    "dark_glasses":{"value" : "true", "confidence" : 72},
    "smiling":{"value" : "false", "confidence" : 35}
}
```

Comment: gender is also an object not an array.

Answer (score 2):

try this one.

```
facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.gender.value
```

Answer (score 0):

getJSON return a promise not the response, you need to use this code:

```
$.getJSON( APIdetect, function(facesDet) {
  console.log( "success" );
  console.log(facesDet);
})
```